# What is reason of these errors while building Vue component

Tags: vue.js, web-component, vue-cli

I am trying to build a vue component and when I run this command:

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-component './src/main.js'
```

I get the following two errors:

> Can't resolve 'vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer' in
> 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\build'
>
> Can't resolve '~root/src/components/HelloWorld.vue?shadow' in
> 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\build'

I am trying to find sth relevant on the internet, but there is not enough info.